# Postfix masquerade local user

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to rewrite in postfix the local user that is sending email from the shell. I'm able to masquerade root@localhost to user@example.com using smtp_generic_maps without a problem.

Unfortunately if I email somewhere like gmail the email is coming from "root (user@example.com)". What would be the best way to manipulate root to something like "User Name"?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you "send mail from the shell."

You're looking at a message From: header, which is part of the e-mail message, and hence not of interest to an MTA like postfix.

When using sendmail(1), set a proper sender address in the RFC822 message you pass to it.

FOr details on how to provide a proper sender address in your chosen mail program, consult its documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Postfix us getting 'root' from `/etc/passwd`. Type `vipw` and change the 5th field.

Comment: Changing the `root` entry in `/etc/passwd` does not sound like the best idea. Especially since the email is not even intended to be send with root as the sender adderss.